# How can i get coordinates in C++?

Tags: c++, char, int, coordinates

I want to get coordinates **x** **y** in one line.

But **x** is `char` type [**a** to **j**] including **a** and **j** ; **y** is `int` type [**1** to **10**] including **1** and **10**.

Example:
`cout>>"Enter coordinates ex[e4] then press enter/n";`

User should write: d5 and **press enter.**

Then i have to separate two input letter(character) and number.

I think that this could be done with `getline` or `getchar`

Can someone explain to me if this is possible and how to this?

Note that the couple **letternumber** (without space ex: f3) must be separated for two different function one based on `char` type the other one bases on `int` type

**Thanks for all the answers. Don't worry, you're not solving my homework, I'm programming a little naval battle game :-) I had no idea on how to do that, all I know is just scholastic experience.**

Here the code: This function checks the `char` value:

```
    int nx;
    nx=x; //Trasfromazione char x in int (NumeroX)
    switch(x) {
        case 97 ... 106:{ //Codice ascii a,b,c...
            return true;
            break;
        }
    default:{
        cout<<"\n---Lettera non valida\a\n\n";
        return false;
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

this function checks the `int` value:

```
bool checknum(int y){
    bool v=false;
    switch(y) {
        case 1 ... 10 :{
            v=true;
            break;
        }
    default:{
        cout<<"\n---Numero non valido\a\n\n";
        return false;
        break;
    }
    }
    return v;   
}
```

and this is the code which calls two function:

```
do{
    cout<<"\n-Inserisci lettera numero\n>";
    cin>>x>>y;
}while(((checknum(y))==false) or((checklett(x))==false) );
```

if my input is two letters this cause an eternal loop

05-02-2020 dd-mm-yyyy Edit for @Tedlyngmo

With this code it seems to work:

```
do{
    cout<<"\n-Inserisci lettera e numero\n>";
    cin>>x>>y;
    cin.clear();    
}while((checklett(x)==false)or(checknum(y)==false));
```

do you know why?

Comment: the most naive approach using `std::cin` should work. Please show your code

Comment: 1/ get a string as input. 2/ split the string into one alphabetic character and one numeric character. 3/ write functions to convert those into the integer indices you probably want

Comment: @Useless why so compilcated? `istream` can do all that for you

Comment: It can do 1 & 2, sure. The problem is that OP doesn't seem to have realized that 3 is a separate step, and is failing to break their problem down into achievable chunks.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Don't worry, you're not solving my homework, I'm programming a little naval battle game :-) I had no idea on how to do that, all I know is just scholastic experience.

Comment: In your previous question you said that you are studying in a scientific high school in italy, and that your professor did not explain much. The battleship game is a very common homework task in c++ courses. So I don't believe you. Next time show your own attempts at least..

Comment: ANFAMI  TENETELI I COMMENTI. You're free to believe in what you want. My conscience is fine.

Comment: @TedLyngmo checks the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the formatted input capabilities of any `std::istream` (like `std::cin`).

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char letter;
    int number;

    if(std::cin >> letter >> number) {
        std::cout << "success. got letter " << letter << " and number " << number << '\n';
    } else {
        // failure
    }
}
```

Edit: The updated question now shows problem when `std::cin` enters a failed state. Here's one way to clear that state and to throw away garbage characters still in the buffer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

// A function template to read a value from a stream and to validate it
template<typename T>
bool get_val(std::istream& is, T min, T max, T& out) {
    if(is >> out) {
        return out >= min && out <= max;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    char letter;
    int number;

    while(true) {
        std::cout << "Enter coordinates: ";
        if(get_val<char>(std::cin, 'a', 'j', letter) &&
           get_val<int>(std::cin, 1, 10, number))
        {
            // success
            break;
        } else {
            // failure
            if(std::cin.eof()) {
                // end of file, the user is not there anymore
                std::cout << "Abort...\n";
                return 1;
            }
            std::cout << "Invalid input\n";
            // clear error state
            std::cin.clear();
            // clear input buffer to newline
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Got letter " << letter << " and number " << number << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Isn't this obviously a homework question that you should not answer with working code?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Don't worry, you're not solving my homework, I'm programming a little naval battle game :-) I had no idea on how to do that, all I know is just scholastic experience

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you very much! I marked your answer as the best, but i won't use your code. Because this is my game, and i want to program it by myself. I know that your code is better than mine, I respect you, but all my knowledge comes from scholastic experiences that were only one year. We learned function and nothing else. I dont think that i can do it with function so I leave it as it is. If you want to see all my code probably it will the worst code you have seen ahahahhahaha. Thank you anyway bro! And sorry for my english =)

Comment: @saporedisale You are welcome! Most of the code on SO is here just to show some options, spark some ideas or to clarify how something works. So, pick the pieces you like and skip the rest. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo is `cin.ignore` useless in this situation? maybe before or after `cin>>x>>y`

Comment: @saporedisale It depends :-) It should not be done before or after `cin>>x>>y` unless an error occurs since it's throwing away everything to the next newline. You could change it to just `std::cin.ignore()` which throws away one `char` instead and then it'll try to extract again with the rest of the `char`s on the line, if there are any. That'd work in the case where you may enter a whole row of coordinates on one line.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hey man, it's me another time, ahahahha. Could you check my answer? Because i found a solution and i really want your opinion about it

Comment: @saporedisale When you do `cin>>x>>y` you should check if `cin` is still in a "good" state (i.e. the extraction succeeded). `if(cin>>x>>y) {good} else {bad}` -  If the user just entered something bad, you can `cin.clear()` the error state, remove the offending character(s) and try again - but if it failed because of `eof()` it can never succeed and trying to get input from the user should stop. Those things are mainly what the `while` loop in my answer deals with.

Comment: @saporedisale ... and I noticed that you used a non-standard case range extension. Use `if(value >= min && value <= max) {good} else {bad}` instead if you want to stay with standard C++ - which is what the range checking function template `get_val` does in my answer - and it works for both `char`s and `int`s :-)

Comment: And regarding the question "_it seems to work ... do you know why?_": Yes, it _seems_ to work but has the potential for _Undefined Behavior_ if you don't initialize `x` and `y`  before the extraction since you read the variables without checking that the extraction succeeded. You also `clear()` the state unconditionally but you don't remove the offending character so if you enter `ab` on one line and then just `2` on the second, it will interpret that as `b2`. Users usually expect to start each line without any hidden values in the buffer - which is what the long `ignore` line deals with.

Comment: If I would use `cin.clear()` ,what is wrong with my code?

Comment: @saporedisale You **are** using `cin.clear()` in the piece of code I commented on - and it's wrong for the reasons I mentioned in that comment + that it doesn't take care of `eof()`. I forgot to mention that problem.

Comment: You mentioned `eof()` , `cin.good()` and `cin.ignore()`. Could you explain to me how to use them?

Comment: Look at the code in my answer and the comments I written in it. You could draw a flow chart from it to visualize what it's doing.

.... and you can read more about the functions used @ [`std::istream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream)

Comment: ok thank you. just one another thing, i tried the case you said above("so if you enter ab on one line and then just 2 on the second, it will interpret that as b2.") but it works

Comment: For the reasons I mentioned, I wouldn't call that working. No user would expect `2` on a single line ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dsG645)) to be accepted and to get `b2` as a result. Also, if the user closes his/her input stream (by pressing CTRL-D on some platforms) you will not notice the `eof()` and it'll spin forever.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve what you ask is by reading the input with `cin` in a `char[2]`, so the letter will be stored in `char[0]` and the number in `char[1]`, or you can read it in separated variables, with a `char` storing the letter and an `int` storing the number:

```
int main()
{
    char s[2];
    // In a char array
    printf("Enter coordinates: ");
    std::cin >> s;

    // In separated char and int variables
    char a;
    int b;
    printf("Enter coordinates: ");
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @0xbaadf00d why not ? There is no such rule! The question lacks quality, but not because it is homework. There is nothing wrong with questions about homework

Comment: "It's usually better not to provide a complete code sample if you believe it would not help the student, using your best judgment."

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @0xbaadf00d i completely agree with this statement, but imho it applies when the question is about a problem that the student is supposed to solve. Here however, the problem is that OP didnt open a book to read the most basic example of getting user input. I see no value in not providing the answer

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Don't worry, you're not solving my homework, I'm programming a little naval battle game :-)

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo now I can't write. I will explain to you this evening if you want. Thank you

Comment: I removed my comment and will demonstrate it instead. Possibly in 10 hours or so when I'm at my computer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank for your help. I have already done naval battle ship and i use two separate `cin` one for letter and the other one for number. i dont know if it is possible to write in one line letter and number and press enter to get coordinates. you must know that i have two functions that check if letter and number  are correct. Did you understand me? i tried but an input of two letter cause a eternal loop

Comment: @saporedisale Writing a onliner is not important at all. Making the code robust is! Using the `std::cin >> s;`idea (where `s` is a `char[2]`) in this answer is anything but robust. An eternal loop is probably the result of your input stream being in a failed state - but - if you are using the advice in this answer (untill the formatted input was added) you are doomed. I can't say much else than that it's a disaster waiting to happen. Make programs that lets users enter stuff however they like without crashing the program. If the program can't interpret the input - tell the user - don't crash.

Comment: @saporedisale Here's an example of why this proposed solution is a terrible idea: https://godbolt.org/z/q4AV9D

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

```
std::cout << "Enter coordinates ex[e4] then press enter/n";
char x;
int y;
std::cin >> x >> y;
```

Comment: Isn't this obviously a homework question that you should not answer?

Comment: @0xbaadf00d a) How do you know this is homework? b) Why do you think question about homework should not be answered?

Comment: @0xbaadf00d the problem with the question is not that it is homework. The problem is that OP obviously took zero effort to find an answer on their own and it is completely unclear what problem they are facing

Comment: a) it seems quite obvious to me, nobody would write this kind of software b) They can and SHOULD be answered, not with working code though.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d I dont want to keep the discussion alive, just consider that the accepted answer in the meta post also says: "Don't downvote others who answer homework questions in good faith, even if they break these guidelines". If you think this question should not be answered, just flag it and move on ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Don't worry, you're not solving my homework, I'm programming a little naval battle game :-) I had no idea on how to do that, all I know is just scholastic experience.

Answer (score -3):

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
std::cout << str;
```

then do what you want with your string, e.g.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol
from first letter

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Don't worry, you're not solving my homework, I'm programming a little naval battle game :-) I had no idea on how to do that, all I know is just scholastic experience.

Comment: When it comes to the question, "_I have to separate two input letter(character) and number. [...] Can someone explain to me if this is possible and how to this?_", I don't see that this provides much help